# SQL select one of the multiple returned rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database of cars with Make, Model, Year and Drive type
I am searching by Make, Model and year to get the drive type of certain cars.
The Problem I am having is that some cars return multiple Drive types I.E A GMC YUKON 2002 returns 3 4WD, RWD, AWD. Basically, the logic I want to follow is if there is more than one drive type if AWD exists use that else if 4WD exists use that and if both AWD and 4WD exist use AWD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you what to return only 1 car, you can use this

```
SELECT TOP 1 ... 
ORDER CASE drive
WHEN 'AWD' THEN 1
WHEN '4WD' THEN 2
WHEN 'RWD' THEN 3
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked like a charm. I was not aware you could do a case statement in an order by

Answer (score 0):

Sub-Select the drive type for each MMY, getting the Top 1 Drive type Ordered by a CASE expression.